# export huge data from elastic search

Tags: java, performance, elasticsearch, jvm

I am writing a java api (reporting Api )that is exports a huge data from elastic search, I was test the code but I found many spikes in the Gc activities I need recommendations to tune the jvm  params and the  Gc prams

```
-verbose:gc -Xloggc:/opt/jboss/standalone/log/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -server -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:NewRatio=2 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Duser.timezone=GMT -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dfile.io.encoding=UTF-8 -DjavaEncoding=UTF-8 -Xms2300m -Xmx2300m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -Dspring.profiles.active=loadtest -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.payfort.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.payfort. Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/opt/jboss/standalone/log/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/opt/jboss/standalone/configuration/logging.properties -jar /opt/jboss/jboss-modules.jar -mp /opt/jboss/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/opt/jboss -Djboss.server.base.dir=/opt/jboss/standalone -c standalone.xml
```

[image]

Comment: Which Java version you are using? Are you settings any GC flags? Graph looks normal that is how GC is designed

Comment: I am using java 8 , no gc flags

Comment: Please provide query examples and used endpoints, index size and schema. Usually the problem is in incorrect api usage. In most cases it is enough to increase heap size

Comment: Also note that ES is information retrieval engine - this means it fast in case of search but not optimal in data extracting. Without technical details it is hard to provide any useful advise.